# Getting the error "TypeError: Page is not a constructor."

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting the problem for page is not a constructor, have tried everything but still getting this problem. I thought it might be the JQuery but have checked everything seems alright.

> "TypeError: Page is not a constructor."

```
admin_pages.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Get Page model
var Page = require('../models/page');


router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Page.find({}).sort({sorting: 1}).exec(function (err, pages) {
        res.render('admin/pages', {
            pages: pages
        });   
    });
});


router.get('/add-page', function(req, res) {
    
    var title = "";
    var slug = "";
    var content = "";

    res.render('admin/add_page', {
        title: title,
        slug: slug,
        content: content
    });

});

router.post('/add-page', function(req, res) {
    
    req.checkBody('title', 'Title must have a value.').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('content','Content must have a value.').notEmpty();

    var title = req.body.title;
    var slug = req.body.slug.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    if (slug == "") slug = title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    var content = req.body.content;

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        res.render('admin/add_page', {
            errors: errors,
            title: title,
            slug: slug,
            content: content
        });
    } else {
        Page.findOne({slug: slug}, function(err, Page) {
            if (page) {
                req.flash('danger', 'Page slug exists, choose another.');
                res.render('admin/add_page', {
                    title: title,
                    slug: slug,
                    content: content
                });
            } else {
                var page = new Page({
                    title: title,
                    slug: slug,
                    content: content,
                    sorting: 100
                });

                page.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        return console.log(err);

                    req.flash('success', 'page added!');
                    res.redirect('/admin/pages');                            
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

router.post('/reorder-pages', function(req, res) {
    var ids = req.body['id[]'];

    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++ ) {
        var id = ids[i];
        count++

        (function(count) {
        page.findById(id, function (err, page) {
            page.sorting = count;
            page.save(function (err) {
                if (err)
                    return console.log(err);
            });
        });
        }) (count);   
    }
});


module.exports = router;
```

[image: page.js file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Page.findOne({slug: slug}, function(err, Page) {
                                         ^
```

On this line you are overshadowing `Page`. Surely you meant to use `page` (lower-case P) as your variable name.

```
Page.findOne({slug: slug}, function(err, page) {
                                         ^
```

Later, you try to use `new Page()` but this Page is not the Page you think it is (leading to the error).